# Returning List from Firestore Listen callback

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function in firebase that is intended to get all documents in a collection called `history` and add it to a list intended to be returned.

The problem is, and I think this is because `.listen()` is async, the list returned is always empty. I know the data is queried correctly because I can print the doc in the `forEach` function, but adding to a list outside doesn't work.

By the way, `myStream` is a snapshot of the history collection in FireStore.

Does my function need to be a Future? How can I make this work?

Here is my code:

```
List getHistory(String id) {
  List history;

  Firestore.instance.collection(id).snapshots().listen((data) {
    data.documents.forEach(
      (doc) => history.add(doc['day']),
    );
  });

  return history;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your function will have to return a [`Future`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html).
As you correctly pointed out, the way Firestore data is retrieved is *asynchronous*. This means that whereever you want to use this data, you will have to `await` a `Future`.
If you want to do this in your UI, you can just make use of [Flutter's `FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

However, firstly you need to refactor your `getHistory` function.
You will not be able to use the [`snapshots`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) function if you just want to get the history once. If you do want to use real-time updates, then you can just translate everything I say to a [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), but then you cannot return your `List`, you could only `yield` it (I will just include an example implementation at the end).
Having said that, I am going to use the [`getDocuments` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html) for the `FutureBuilder` example.

### Get data once

```dart
Future<List> getHistory(String id) async {
  List history;

  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = 
      (await Firestore.instance.collection(id).getDocuments()).documents;

  history = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['day']).toList();

  return history;
}
```

*Notice* that I added the `async` keyword to be able to `await` the `getDocuments` call and wrapped the return type in a `Future`. I used the [`List.map` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) to map the `DocumentSnapshot`'s to your `day` value (I also changed your `myStream` to a Firestore call because I cannot know the objects you actually use in your class, thus you will have to exchange that with how you access your Firestore collection).
In the next step, I will include an example implementation of how you would use this function in your UI using `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getHistory(id),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data
          .map((day) => ListTile(
                title: Text('$day'),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  },
);
```

I simply used a `ListView` to demonstrate how you could use your list of data in your UI.

### Real-time updates

Because I mentioned it earlier, here would be an example implementation for having real-time updates using `Stream` (you would have to exchange your `FutureBuilder` with a `StreamBuilder` if you wanted to use it in your UI):

```dart
Stream<List> getHistory(String id) {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> documents = Firestore.instance.collection(id).snapshots();

  return documents.map((querySnapshot) {
    List history;
    final documents = querySnapshot.documents;

    history = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['day']);

    return history;
  });
}
```

In this case, I am just mapping the `Stream`, which will apply the mapping operation for every data event. I mentioned `yield` above, but it is not necessary to use that here. You could use `yield` in the following manner, which would be closer to your initial implementation:

```dart
Stream<List> getHistory(String id) async* {
  await for (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot in Firestore.instance.collection(id).snapshots()) {
    List history;
    final documents = querySnapshot.documents;

    history = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['day']);

    yield history;
  }
}
```

This is probably just confusing and it is completely unnecessary here, so just ignore it :)

Comment: Wow, thank you so so much! This was beyond helpful! Futures are really confusing and I have been trying to grasp the concept but you made it so easy to understand! Also, the way you rewrote the `getHistory` function to map the snapshot and append to list was exactly what I couldn't figure out. This was the best answer I have ever gotten on Stack Overflow, thank you so much!