# synchronous firestore callback needs to load in auto complete text view in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, callback

I am stuck with a small issue. I have data in firestore document which should be loaded in autocomplete text view. However, my firestore callback is returning data after my autocomplete code execute. My question is how to load data after callback completes returning document data successfully.
Following is my code...

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_instructor);

    activitySearchInstructorBinding=ActivitySearchInstructorBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view=activitySearchInstructorBinding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);

     fillInstructorList();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: instructorList into ACTV...");
    AutoCompleteInstructorAdapter autoCompleteInstructorAdapter = new AutoCompleteInstructorAdapter(this,instructorList);
    activitySearchInstructorBinding.searchInstructorInstructorIdACTV.setAdapter(autoCompleteInstructorAdapter);
    activitySearchInstructorBinding.searchInstructorInstructorIdACTV.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void fillInstructorList(){
    Log.d(TAG, "fillInstructorList: Inside function...");
    instructorList = new ArrayList<>();
    instructorList.add(new Instructor("HI821010A01","Himani Kumar","40","5",
            "$50","20","10","M"));
    documentReference=firebaseFirestoreDB.document(instructorsCollectionRoot+"/"+"NSW");


    documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = (DocumentSnapshot) task.getResult();
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "fillInstructorList: document exists...");

                    Map<String, Object> dataMap = documentSnapshot.getData();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: hMap size: " + dataMap.size());

                    for(Map.Entry m : dataMap.entrySet()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: m.getKey(): " + m.getKey());
                        HashMap<String,String> innerMap = (HashMap<String, String>) m.getValue();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: hMap size: " + innerMap.size());
                        String instructorID=null,instructorName=null,instructorAge=null,instructorRating=null,
                                instructorRate=null,drivingSince=null,instructorSince=null,instructorGender=null;
                        for(Map.Entry innerm : innerMap.entrySet()) {
                            if(innerm.getKey().equals("instructorID")) instructorID=innerm.getValue().toString();
                            if(innerm.getKey().equals("instructorName")) instructorName=innerm.getValue().toString();
                        }
                        instructorList.add(new Instructor(instructorID,instructorName,instructorAge,instructorRating,
                                instructorRate,drivingSince,instructorSince,instructorGender));
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: instructorList.size: " + instructorList.size());
                    }

                }
                else
                    Log.d(TAG, "fillInstructorList: document doesn't exists :P");
            }else
                Log.d(TAG, "fillInstructorList: task is not successful");

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to fill your Adapter once the data loads, since reading in firebase is an asynchronous process. Here an example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_instructor);

    // ...

    fillInstructorList();
}

public void fillInstructorList() {
    // ...
    documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            // Validation and data fill process
            AutoCompleteInstructorAdapter autoCompleteInstructorAdapter = new AutoCompleteInstructorAdapter(this,instructorList);
            activitySearchInstructorBinding.searchInstructorInstructorIdACTV.setAdapter(autoCompleteInstructorAdapter);
            activitySearchInstructorBinding.searchInstructorInstructorIdACTV.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this, my app crashes in this case. May be reason is, setOnItemClick is trying to call in callback which seems wrong logically. Let me know your thought pls

Comment: Following post is looking relevant to me but not sure how to make it fit in my code...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263974/returning-list-from-firestore-listen-callback

Comment: Ok, First you could put a bit of the stacktrace to analyze where it crashes. This to help you if everything is logically correct